# unable to find user root: no matching entries in passwd file

Tags: docker

I have a running Docker container with the following:

```
docker exec -it cc58908a8dc2 /bin/bash
```

I ran this command before on other containers and it worked just fine.
Now, however, I'm getting this issue:

```
unable to find user root: no matching entries in passwd file
```

My `Dockerfile` has the following contents:

```
# We will be running our Spark jobs as `root` user.
USER root

# Working directory is set to the home folder of `root` user.
WORKDIR /root
```

Any idea of what could cause this?

Comment: It would be nice to have the Dockerfile

Comment: Which image are you using ?

Comment: I've updated my post

Comment: That's your whole Dockerfile? Then your image is basically empty.

Comment: Not my whole Dockerfile, just the part seems relevant.

Comment: More relevant is the base image you are using i.e. the `FROM` line.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sometimes, after restarting the Docker container that message appears.

If instead of restarting like this:
`docker restart cc58908a8dc2`

I stopped and started the container like this:

```
docker stop cc58908a8dc2
docker start cc58908a8dc2
```

Then the error disappeared.

Comment: This should be considered a workaround, i don't think in production we can anyhow restart the instances

Comment: We had some containers with "no matching entries in passwd file" issues when trying to exec something inside the containers. With -u UID it worked, with -u USERNAME it dit not work. A restart of the container with the restart command did not solve the issue. A stop of the container followed by a start of the container did solve the issue.

Comment: It is absolutely a workaround, and not one that I can live with... but I'm not sure there is anyone who actually knows the root cause: https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-find-user-root-no-matching-entries-in-passwd-file/26545/4

Comment: well, at least it seems to be an issue on a per-container basis (not a per-dockerd so at least it doesn't affect everything on the node, just random containers... and perhaps suddenly after they've been running for a while) – I haven't used 'docker cp' to trigger the issue, but I have read that it can trigger the issue. I'm pretty sure there's another way too...)

Comment: It worked for me. I am using Docker version 17.06.0-ce on CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get this fixed please remember to comment on https://forums.docker.com/t/unable-to-find-user-root-no-matching-entries-in-passwd-file/26545/9

Also **use the feedback button** from the KB article documenting how to restart docker engine when you encounter it: https://success.docker.com/article/ucp-health-checks-fail-unable-to-find-user-nobody-no-matching-entries-in-passwd-file-observed

It seems that the internet is full with others randomly encountering this bug.

To get an idea about which change you have to encounter it, take at look at http://status.openstack.org/elastic-recheck/index.html#1803544 which is a graph of bug occurence on OpenStack CI jobs, occurds daily.

I know that any software has bugs and that it takes time to fix them, but this bug left me.... more than two years old and the only feedback from Docker was "tracker privatly" and "restart docker".

Answer (score 1):

Restarting containers usually helps (see @octavian answer). If it is not an option try:

> docker exec -it -u 0 cc58908a8dc2 /bin/bash

where **cc58908a8dc2** is the name of your container